# Brackets Live Preview not working after moving to wwwroot

Tags: php, iis, adobe-brackets, live-preview

I'm using Brackets to dev a static, simple site. The Live Preview capability is fantastic. all was going well until...

I wanted to start using some php in my site so i downloaded php and tested it in my inetpub/wwwroot. I then figured that i best move my static site (html and css files) to the wwwroot folder.

This caused a set of issues i partly resolved. My Live preview started asking for base URL so i put the new local url: http://localhost/myprojectfolder/. HTML and PHP files now showing but...

The Live preview needs me to hit save and restart the preview (defeats the purpose of Live Preview). It also doesn't highlight sections of the page as you scroll through the code.

How can i get PHP working on my site and the Live Preview working, i've messed something up.

Edit: Im using IIS with my PHP hence moving my static site to wwwroot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brackets has a known issue whereby the Live Preview requires saving of code and refreshing of live preview chrome screen in order to see change. You can also not see the element highlighting once moving to your own web server eg iis.